# postgresql exist check error, wrong syntax?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to check if row already exists, but it fails and gives me a syntax error this is the code:

```
public boolean checkExist(String table, String info) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM " + table + " WHERE info=" + info + ")");
        return st.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Query:

```
"SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM " + table + " WHERE info=" + info + ")"
```

Throws: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
  Position: 104

Comment: Can you print what the query string looks like after you call the function? I think that error could be caused by 'info' being empty.

Comment: that is a wrong way to use `exists`. How can you have a `select` without a `from`?

Comment: @vkp, in PostgreSQL, the `FROM` clause can be omitted here because `EXISTS` is a [subquery expresssion](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-subquery.html) which always returns a boolean. The root of the problem lays in the misuse of `PreparedStatement`; instead of using a bind variable, the `info` variable is simply conctenated into the query, but the surrounding single quotes are missing. `"SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM " + table + " WHERE info= '" + info + "')"` should work, but even that would be "doing it wrong".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your query is that you're appending the value of `info` into the query literal, but not wrapping it within single quotes as is required in PostgreSQL. So, the query that's sent over to the DB becomes something like

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE info=valueOfInfo)
```

instead of

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE info='valueOfInfo')
```

The correct way to do this is to use *bind variables* with the `PreparedStatement` and only have placeholders (`?`) in the query literal. This way, you don't need to worry about wrapping the variable in quotes, or more importantly, the possibility of SQL injection.

Additionally, you should take care of closing the statement after use; this is easiest done with the [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) (assuming you're on Java 7 or above). So the fixed version of your method could look something like this:

```
public boolean checkExist(String table, String info) {

    final String query = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM " + table
            + " WHERE info = ?)";

    try (PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(query,
             ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)) {
        st.setString(1, info); // bind the variable to the placeholder
        try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery()) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                return rs.getBoolean(1); // EXISTS() returns a boolean
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Throws `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Operation requires a scrollable ResultSet, but this ResultSet is FORWARD_ONLY.` exception

Comment: That seems weird, because nothing in the code should be moving the cursor backwards. Could you try using `PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(query, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,  ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)` instead? (Sorry I cannot test this as I don't have a PostgreSQL installation available).

Comment: Okay, that's good to know; I've edited the correction into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should actually do

```
" SELECT 1 FROM " + table + " WHERE info=" + info + ")" "
```

This would return `1` when a row exists that matches the `where` clause.

Also, use `distinct` if you only need `1` returned, no matter how many rows match the `where` condition, like

```
" SELECT distinct 1 FROM " + table + " WHERE info=" + info + ")" "
```

Comment: Don't concatenate values into query. That causes sql injection vulnerability, use query parameters instead.